# VB6 and COM: cannot use user-defined type parameter in COM function

Tags: com, types, vb6, public, user-defined

I am using a COM object in VB6. The COM object has a function Foo(Long, Long, Rect). Rect is a struct defined in the COM object implementation. My VB6 code (a button on a form) is like below:

```
Private Sub btnTestCom_Click()
    Set ComObj = CreateObject("ObjectName")
    Dim rect As DISPLAY_RECT

    rect.Left = 20
    rect.Top = 20

    ComObj.Foo(101, 0, rect) ' Error here
End Sub
```

At the last line it is giving me this compilation error:
"Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions".

Other COM functions that do not have user-defined type parameters are working fine.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Mitch, what do you mean? DISPLAY_RECT is a struct defined in the 3rd party COM library and I'm referencing to this library.

Comment: The error message is saying that you're not.  So does your code, you wouldn't have to use CreateObject() if you are referencing a COM type library.  You must use the DISPLAY_RECT that came from the same type library as the one that declared "ObjectName".  A different one with the same name cannot work, it will have a different guid.

Comment: @Hans has a good point. Check which DISPLAY_RECT is being used. I've edited my answer to suggest one way to do that (search for DISPLAY_RECT in the object browser)

Comment: Hi @Hans, what do you mean by "you wouldn't have to use CreateObject() if you are referencing a COM type library"? I always used COM in VB6 like this: (1) add reference to the library (2) call obj = CreateObject(classname) (3) call obj.Foo(), obj.Bar()

Comment: Then you've been always been doing it the wrong way.  The point of adding a type library is that you don't have to use CreateObject().  You just use Dim obj As New Foo.  No need for a type library if you use it late bound.

Comment: @Charlie @Hans Hans is right. Late-binding (using `Dim obj As New Foo`) is much better. For example if you use late-binding, it will be easier to get this `ComObj.Foo` method call correct. The IDE will give you "IntelliSense" hints about the parameter types as you type, and the compiler will check whether you have got them correct.

Answer (score 1):

The function call is [late-bound](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115) because your variable `ComObj` is not typed. You could try declaring it, something like

```
Dim ComObj As SomeObjectDefinedInComImplementation
```

**EDIT**

I would also check that you are actually using the `DISPLAY_RECT` from the COM library. Open up the object browser (press F2) and search all libraries for `DISPLAY_RECT`.

- If you only see one result, check whether it's from the correct COM library.

  - If it's from the correct COM library, there must be another problem.
  - If it's from the wrong COM library: check whether you actually have the correct library referenced (in project references). If you definitely do already have it referenced, double-check whether you really are supposed to pass a `DISPLAY_RECT`
- If you see multiple results, VB6 may be picking up the wrong library. Try explicitly qualifying the `DISPLAY_RECT` with the name of the library `Dim rect As TheCorrectLibraryName.DISPLAY_RECT`

Comment: Beware that there are some odds that he'll only see the wrong one.

Comment: Hi @MarkJ and Hans, sorry I did not make my problem clearer. DISPLAY_RECT is actully "XXX_DISPLAY_RECT". So it is the only correct one from the correct COM library. As MarkJ suggested, there must be another problem. Now I am going to try RS Conley's solution. I'll keep you guys updated. Thanks

Comment: @Charlie You said this was a 3rd party library? In that case I don't think RS Conley's answer is appropriate. The library is expecting a specific type, you must pass the correct type as defined in the library. You can't just create a class of your own and pass that instead. This would be more appropriate if the library was your code, and you could change it too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DISPLY_RECT is a type, you can't pass types into a public COM method or return a type from a public COM Function in VB6. You will have to make a class duplicating the type, and a helper function that takes the class as a parameter and returns the type.